# Mysterious behaviors with pointers. (Internal elements of objects getting changed)

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm trying to build a relational database for the class I'm in.

what's happening is that when I process my "Facts" and "Queries" input, I create a new relation object. And then I print them out. If I run one at a time they process just fine, but if I run them back to back, the second one modifies the contents of the vector of tokens within the other relation object.

#### Database.h

```
class Database
{
private:
    datalogProgram program;
    Relation theSchemes;
    Relation theFacts;
    std::vector<Token> FactsOrder;
public:
    Database(datalogProgram input);
    Database();
    ~Database();
    Relation processSchemes(datalogProgram processme);
    Relation processFacts(datalogProgram processme);
};
```

#### Database.cpp

And I apologize for all of the cout's I've been trying to debug this things for hours!

```
#include "Database.h"
#include <sstream>

Database :: Database(datalogProgram input)
{
    // So first I will make a map with relations representing the Schemes Facts and Queries
    // Thus I will have a database of schemes facts and queries, rules excluded and ignored for now.
    program = input;
    theSchemes = processSchemes(program);
    theFacts = processFacts(program);
    // just checking on progress.
    std::cout << "SCHEMES" << std::endl;
    theSchemes.printRelation();
    std::cout << "FACTS" << std::endl;
    theFacts.printRelation();
}

Database :: Database() {}

Database :: ~Database() {}

Relation Database :: processSchemes(datalogProgram input)
{
    Relation temp;
    // LETS START WITH SCHEMES
    std::cout << "processing schemes" << std::endl;
    std::vector<Scheme>* schemes = input.returnSchemeList();
    // Process First Scheme
    // Populate this first vector with ID's from schemes.
    // std::vector<Token*> firstTuple;
    std::vector<Token*> firstTuple;
    std::vector<Token> idListONE;
    firstTuple.push_back(input.returnFirstScheme()->returnFirstID());
    // std::vector<Token> idListONE;
    idListONE = input.returnFirstScheme()->returnCLEANidLIST();
    for(int i = 0; i < input.returnFirstScheme()->returnCLEANidLIST().size(); i++)
        firstTuple.push_back(&idListONE[i]);
    temp = *new Relation(input.returnFirstScheme()->returnName(), firstTuple);
    // NOW I NEED TO PROCESS THE REST OF THE SCHEMES
    //Take a scheme off of the list, and work on it just like I did above.
    for(int j = 0; j < schemes->size(); j++) {
        // Populate this first vector with ID's from schemes.
        std::vector<Token*> first;
        first.clear();
        first.push_back(schemes->at(j).returnFirstID());
        std::vector<Token> idLista;
        idLista.clear();
        idLista = schemes->at(j).returnCLEANidLIST();
        for(int i = 0; i < schemes->at(j).returnCLEANidLIST().size(); i++)
            first.push_back(&idLista[i]);
        temp.relationInsert(schemes->at(j).returnName(), first);
    }
    return temp;
    //
    // At this point I shoudl have a map with "Schemes" pointing to Relation Objects.
    // I want to verify that this is working, so print out all data collected so far.
}

Relation Database :: processFacts(datalogProgram input)
{
    Relation temporary;
    // NOW WE PROCESS FACTS
    // Order does matter, so I will create a vector to use as a key.
    std::cout << "procesing facts" << std::endl;
    std::vector<Fact>* facts = input.returnFactList();
    std::string OUT2;
    std::ostringstream convert2;
    convert2 << facts->size();
    OUT2 = convert2.str();
    std::cout << "THE NUMBER OF FACTS IS " << OUT2 << std::endl;
    // NOW I NEED TO PROCESS THE REST OF THE
    //Take a scheme off of the list, and work on it just like I did above.
    std::vector<Token*> firstTuple;
    std::vector<Token> idListONE;
    for(int j = 0; j < facts->size(); j++) {
        std::cout << "NEW ITERATION:" <<  std::endl;
        if(j==0) {
            std::cout << "processing first fact" << std::endl;
            // is the first Fact!
            firstTuple.clear();
            std::cout << "processing first fact --> tuple" << std::endl;
            firstTuple.push_back(facts->at(j).returnFirstString());
            idListONE.clear();
            std::cout << "FIRST STRINGLIST" << std::endl;
            idListONE = *facts->at(j).returnCleanStringList();
            for(int i = 0; i < idListONE.size(); i++) {
                std::cout << "FIRST STRING ITER" << std::endl;
                firstTuple.push_back(&idListONE[i]);
            }
            FactsOrder.push_back(*facts->at(j).returnName());
            std::cout << "creating first fact" << std::endl;
            temporary = Relation(facts->at(j).returnName(), firstTuple);
        } else {
            std::cout << "processing A fact (ITER)" << std::endl;
            // Populate this first vector with ID's from schemes.
            std::vector<Token*> first;
            first.clear();
            std::cout << "processing fact, firststring (ITER)" << facts->at(j).returnFirstString()->getTokensValue() << std::endl;
            first.push_back(facts->at(j).returnFirstString());
            std::vector<Token> idLista;
            idLista.clear();
            std::cout << "getting stringlist (ITER)" << std::endl;
            idLista = *facts->at(j).returnCleanStringList();
            for(int i = 0; i < idLista.size(); i++) {
                std::cout << "processing stringlist (ITER) ITER" << std::endl;
                first.push_back(&idLista[i]);
            }
            FactsOrder.push_back(*facts->at(j).returnName());
            std::cout << "adding fact" << std::endl;
            temporary.relationInsert(facts->at(j).returnName(), first);
        }
    }
    return temporary;
}
```

#### relation.cpp

Just so you can see it

```
Relation :: Relation(Token* key,std::vector<Token*> tuple)
{
    std::pair<Token*,std::vector<Token*> > mypair (key,tuple);
    contents.insert(mypair);
}

Relation :: Relation() {}

Relation :: ~Relation() {}

void Relation :: relationInsert(Token* key,std::vector<Token*> tuple)
{
    std::pair<Token*,std::vector<Token*> > mypair (key,tuple);
    contents.insert(mypair);
}

void Relation :: printRelation()
{
    std::cout << "PRINT RELATION CALLED" << std::endl;
    std::multimap<Token*,std::vector<Token*> >::iterator mapIT;
    for(mapIT = contents.begin() ; mapIT != contents.end() ; mapIT ++) {
        std::cout << "Key: " << mapIT->first->getTokensValue() "\nValues:" << std::endl;
        for(int x = 0; x< mapIT->second.size() ; x++)
            std::cout << " " << mapIT->second.at(x)->getTokensValue() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your problem you must figure out object / pointer ownership in your code. `Relation` holds a relation between a pointer to Token and a list of other pointer to Tokens. It is ok to keep `Token*` rather then a copy of Token. (*Especially if tokens can be large words you don't want to copy*). But who "owns" and manages the tokens?

Lets look at an example

```
std::vector<Token*> firstTuple;
std::vector<Token> idListONE;
```

- idListONE is a vector to actual Tokens. It is a function local variable so it will be discarded when we exit the function.

  firstTuple is a vector to pointers of Tokens.

You push into it in the following manner:

```
      firstTuple.push_back(&idListONE[i]);
```

So firstTuple tokens are pointers to the internal tokens inside idListONE. That **might** be valid but you must remember that as soon as idListONE is released or its memory is changed (its size increased for instance) firstTuple becomes invalid, because it will now point at memory that was released and using it may have undefined results and will likely crash the program.

Actually a few lines later you make that mistake:

```
 temporary = Relation(facts->at(j).returnName(), firstTuple);
```

temporary is a Relation that holds a list to pointer of Tokens. It copies the list that means that it copies the token pointers. However the pointers it copies are to Tokens that belong to `idListONE` as soon as you exit the function `idListONE` is released and the pointers inside the Relation are no longer valid and using them is likely one source of the problems you are seeing. **There might be additional problems like this in the code**

In general there seems to be a lot of confusion about working with pointers vs working with objects.

Look at the following statement:

```
temp = *new Relation(input.returnFirstScheme()->returnName(), firstTuple);
```

`new Relation(...)` will allocate memory on the heap and initialize a Relation.

`temp = *<ptr>` will use operator= to copy the content on the right into `temp`. The Relation on the heap is forgotten and its memory is **leaked**.

Another example:

```
    idListONE.clear();
    std::cout << "FIRST STRINGLIST" << std::endl;
    idListONE = *facts->at(j).returnCleanStringList();
```

first you clear idListONE then you use the operator= to overwrite it with a new list.

- Why did you clear a list you are writing over?

  Why do you return a pointer to a list from returnCleanStringList()? instead of a copy list or a const ref to an internal list?

  If you decided returnCleanStringList() should return a list by pointer rather then by value then why is the first thing you do is copying it?

Finally you really should choose one style and conform to it. In the long run it makes code clearer.

If you Camelize variable names then always do: idListONE -> idListOne

Also avoid members like 'idListONE', do you really need a different variables for the first index?

Comment: You are absolutely right, I'm not doing very good at keeping track of my objects ownership. I traced a few things back, including what you pointed out, brought ownership up front (passing tokens all the way to the top), which is probably wasting some space, but this way I'm not confused. I changed my relations to hold the string value of my tokens because it was having trouble sorting tokens that weren't pointers. Anyway, I'll have to keep getting more experience working with pointers before I'm clean. Thanks!

Comment: To sort Tokens properly the easiest thing to do is just define an operator< on Token